# What happens to plain old Java objects when used by a web application by multiple users?

Tags: java, object, web, pojo

I am trying to create a simple service-like application. I am using the browser as the entry point, servlet as the receiver of the request and a couple of helper java classes. For example, I have user `A` go use the application at the same time as user `B`.

Now my question is, what happens to the helper classes when multiple users access the service? Do they get instantiated every time a user uses the application? 5 users, do they (helper classes) get instantiated 5 times, or for all the users, there is only one copy of everything?

Comment: I don't understand, are the pojos the helper classes? or you know what happens to the pojos but not sure what happens to the helper classes?

Comment: i'm sorry for the unclear explanation. the pojos are the helper classes. i am not sure what happens to them when multiple users use the web application.

Comment: @simon: It's not possible to provide an answer without having a look at your code. There are several ways to use Java classes (and objects).

Comment: Are they static? Instantiated? Class? Instance? Local? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on when and where you instantiate those POJOs. If you are instantiating them on your doGet or doPost then you create new instances of those objects on every request(and discard them after the request has been responded to). Now if you are 'lazy instantiating' them onto a longer memory scope(session, etc) then you retain them longer(e.g. for session scope, throughout the life time of the session).

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is that whenever you are using the `new YourClasseName()`, you are instantiating a new object.

Since the servlet container allocates a thread for each new request for a single servlet (unless you had done some sort of special changes), then simply put, 5 users = 5 threads = 5 calls to construct your pojos. Meaning your objects get instantiated 5 times.

Comment: hey thanks @omarello, I got kinda confused with how servlets act. but you explained it clearly. appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go back and read about class instantiation and their life cycle in java first. And to be more specific to your situation, please provide code snippets. It will depend on how you instantiate your helper classes, 3 possibilities that I can think of:

1- Regular helper class

This is the case where you simply call `Helper h = new Helper();` and you just call actions on your helper classes `h.doHelp(param)` - each time your Servlet call this, it creates new instance of the `Helper` class. Unless of course your helper class use any static variables.

2 - Singleton

When you implement your Helper class as a Singleton and your Servlet calls it the way Singleton are created, eg `Helper h = Helper.getInstance()` If you do it that way, then every request to the Servlet share the same instance of the Hepler class

3 - Static class

If your helper class are just using static methods, eg. `Helper.doHelp(param);` then there's also no sharing between the different request, unless of course your helper class use any static variables.

Comment: well I am only using the regular helper classes. at then end of the instantiation i have h1, h2, h3 each with their own helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your helper classes should be singletons, That way both the userA and userB will use the same instance instead of instantiating twice.

Comment: i think i can do that, but would it be better if i do a create and destroy cycle for every request?